# Magento - Getting user previous order products for his account page?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I'm a noob at Magento, but I was wondering if it was possible to get the users previously purchased products in his account pages?

Like last time he ordered coke and fanta.  He can go to his account page and have a listing of these to re-order them quickly.

Can you tell me a) is it possible?  and B) Some basic outline steps on how I could get to that.

Thanks a bunch for the help.

Comment: It must be possible since account pages already show past orders and (depending on the theme) have a re-order link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @clockworkgeek said, it's totally do-able. An easy (but not very clean) way to make it would be to load all his orders, and then foreach orders load the items, then you filter the duplicates. But that could be quite consuming.

The clean way would be to build a proper query. If I remember well, there should be a table for "ordered items", it could be easily done with a join on those two tables.